# Why rectangular waveguides are more popular in RF/Microwave compare to circular waveguides?

Tags: antenna

I have seen in telecommunication, normally rectangular waveguide is used as the transmission line, what is the reason behind this? Why not circular waveguide is used?

Comment: Probably something to do with the dominant modes they operate at. The dominant mode of rectangular waveguide is  lower than that of circular. TE_10 vs TE_11

Comment: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide_(electromagnetism)  The shape of the waveguide sets the **dominant mode** at which the wave travels through the waveguide.

Comment: Also I think calculations for analysis of rectangular waveguide can be simplified more easily. Circular waveguide requires Bessel functions whereas rectangular uses a bit of trig.

Comment: I imagine it's also easier to make boxes as opposed to round tubes, the location and quality of the joint can be *very* important when running at higher powers.

Comment: Your profile indicates that you're an RF/Microwave engineer at Keysights EEsof division with 14+ years of experience, but the question that you've asked are fairly basic / fundamental. I would expect that someone who has reviewed technical articles in this area to know waveguides and what reference impedance is... especially if you're at Keysight.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Expert may also have some doubt so it's better to take another expert opinion from people like you.https://anilkrpandey.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of mode propagation.  the highest possible bandwidth allowing only a single mode to propagate with circular waveguides is only 1.3601:1.

Rectangular waveguides have a much larger bandwidth over which only a single mode can propagate.

I suggest you try Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waveguide_(electromagnetism)